# Not getting all images inside the album Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using graph api, I am not able to get all images inside a particular images. For some albums I get all the images but for some I don't.

This is how I am getting the images,

```
FB.api('/' + albumId + '/photos?limit=10&access_token='+cookie_access_token, function (photos) {

});
```

Any views on it?

Comment: you have limit=10 ......

Comment: yeah because I am doing pagination. In some of my albums where count is 31 I am only getting 3.